# Removing all columns with all NAs in a data.frame without a loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, na

I want to remove all columns that are all `NA`. I have two solutions as shown below, but they both use looping structures under the hood.

I was wondering if there is a faster solution that does NOT require using `...apply` or `for` loops?

***PS.*** if I wanted to remove all rows with all `NA` I could avoid loops like so: `r[rowSums(is.na(r)) != ncol(r), ]` but can a similar solution apply to columns?

```
r <- data.frame(AA = c(1, NA, 3), BB = c(NA, NA, NA), CC = c(3, NA, 5) )

r[sapply(r, function(r) !all(is.na(r)))] # Solution 1

Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), r)    # Solution 2
```

Comment: Checking each column to see if it consist exclusively of `NA` values by definition means that R has to iterate that column under the hood at some point.  I don't have a problem with your current solutions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Not necessarily. For example, if I wanted to remove all rows with all `NA` I could avoid loops like so: `r[rowSums(is.na(r)) != ncol(r), ]` but how about columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to `rowSums` for rows,  we can use `colSums` for columns

```
r[, colSums(is.na(r)) != nrow(r)]

#  AA CC
#1  1  3
#2 NA NA
#3  3  5
```